# Redis increment keyN or key:N

Tags: redis, lua

in Redis, increment value can be stored or we can increment value of keys. Like

```
127.0.0.1:6379> set _inc 0
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> INCR _inc
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> INCR _inc
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379> get _inc
"2"
```

or we can save items like

```
item:UNIQUE-ID

item:UNI-QUE-ID
```

But how to save items with increment N ID like:

```
item:1
item:2
item:3
item:4
...
```

So far I found a solution with LUA Script

```
127.0.0.1:6379> eval 'return redis.call("set", "item:" .. redis.call("incr","itemNCounter"), "item value")' 0
OK
...
127.0.0.1:6379> keys item:*
 1) "item:10"
 2) "item:14"
 3) "item:13"
 4) "item:6"
 5) "item:15"
 6) "item:9"
 7) "item:4"
 8) "item:1"
 9) "item:5"
10) "item:3"
11) "item:12"
12) "item:7"
13) "item:8"
14) "item:11"
15) "item:2"
```

Question: Is there a method to make it without running Lua script or reliable  method?

I expect that there would be a Redis command to make it.

Comment: What's wrong with Lua script?

Comment: I mean there might a different solution with Redis commands, excluding `eval`

Comment: AFAIK, Lua scripting should be the best way so far.

Answer (score 2):

> Question: Is there a method to make it without running Lua script or reliable method?

No, there isn't. However, `EVAL` is supported since Redis version 2.6 and LUA scripts are first-class citizens in Redis.